# plotting methods to numerous possible axes on the same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created some classes for other users to use and supplied convenience functions to easily get one plot, including figure and axis generation.

```
import pylab as plt
def plot_something():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.plot(xrange(10), axes=ax)
    return fig, ax
def even_more_impressive_plot():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.plot([x**2 for x in xrange(10)], axes=ax)
    return fig, ax
```

But than there is this one crazy user, that would like to be able to use these plots, but in one figure side by side, my first idea didnt work out:

```
desired_fig, desired_axes = plt.subplots(2)
dummy_fig, dummy_ax = plot_something()
dummy_fig2, dummy_ax2 = even_more_impressive_plot()
desired_axes[0] = dummy_ax
desired_axes[1] = dummy_ax2
plt.show()
```

but this, sadly, leaves the desired_axes empty. Is there a simple method or do I have to split the methods like this:

```
def _plot_something(ax):
    plt.plot(xrange(10), axes=ax)

def plot_something2():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    _plot_something(ax)
    return fig, ax
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could design your plotting function in such a way that it is able to work with `fig` and `ax` objects if those are passed as parameters:

```
def plot_something(fig=None, ax=None):
    if fig is None and ax is None:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    elif fig is None:
        fig = ax.get_figure()
    elif ax is None:
        ax = fig.gca()
    ax.plot(xrange(10))
    return fig, ax
```

Then, whenever you need to use the same figure but different ax you can pass them as arguments to your plotting function:

```
desired_fig, desired_axes = plt.subplots(2)
dummy_fig, dummy_ax = plot_something(desired_fig, desired_axes[0]) # or desired_axes[1] depending on where you need to plot
```

Or you can design a different function to use axes arrays...

Comment: Also see this section of the docs http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#coding-styles

Comment: And you should return the artists added, not the the figure/axes

Comment: This does the trick and looks nicer than two methods as above. I'll update my methods accordingly. @tcaswell Returning the artists makes sense, also in this case I'd also return figure and axes.